# HTML5 Drag and Drop not working (with AngularJS)

Tags: html, angularjs, drag-and-drop

I have the following basics:

```
<div draggable="true" dir1>Blah</div>
<div class="drop" dir2></div>
```

I don't want to see the 'ghost image', and I don't want a smooth drag & drop (i.e., the div being dragged snaps to certain positions.

As such, I thought I can do this:

```
app.directive('dir1', function() {
    return function(scope, element, attr) {
        element.bind('dragstart', function(event) {
            event.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = 'move';
            event.dataTransfer.setData('Text', scope.someData);
            event.preventDefault(); // this is to prevent the ghost image
        }
        // My snapping calculation and rendering is done here
    }
}
app.directive('dir2', function() {
    return function(scope, element, attr) {
        element.bind('drop', function(event) {
            event.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = 'move';
            var data = event.dataTransfer.getData('Text');
            event.preventDefault(); // this is to prevent the ghost image
        }
    }
}
```

but this doesn't work! What can I do?

Comment: Try $scope.$apply inside directives

Comment: @Kousha, i know, its too late for answer this but i give a comment to your question. effectAllowed is just for allowed or disallowed effects and its not real effect.Its used for file dragging and something like this... so if you want to do dragging without ghost image you should handle mousedown and mousemove event and change position of your draggable element.